# Chart.js : Stacked bars + minBarLength makes the bar overflow the scale

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart that displays 2 different kind of data in a stacked bar format, with a logarithmic scale using Chart.js 3.7.1

When the 2nd kind of data is too small compared to the 1st kind, it became too thin to be viewed, so I added a `minBarLength`. But now, the bar overflows the scale (presumably because the total length is calculated without the minimal length) : [image: Chart]

How can I do to add some space on the right of the chart ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by calculating the length of the longest bar, doubling the number and adding it into `options.scales.x.max`